# sp_image_is_loaded always returns true

Tags: spotify

So I am loading an album image for a track, I get the pointer for an `sp_image` and then wait for it to finish loading before getting the byte byte with `sp_image_data` (`sp_image`, `data`), but the thing is that the `sp_image_loaded` always checks out as true, even the image is not loaded and the `sp_image_data` returns the error "Resource not loaded yet".

Am I doing something wrong? I did not use the callback because of wanting to do the image fetching synchronized.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that the `sp_image` struct is memset to 0 before initializing it. That can be the cause of many such problems like this.